# Why does getUIThemeDisplay and getUITheme returns Theme3 when used in Community even though the user is using Lightning UI?

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, digital-experience

I have a Community page where I use a lightning web component which have a variable decorated with @wire and linked to Apex class method which returns the User.getUIThemeDisplay.
For some reason the User.getUIThemeDisplay and User.getUITheme always return the "Theme3" value, even though the user is actually using Lightning and the value should have been "Theme4d".
I want to render a link in my LWC based on the theme the user is using, and I need to know the that theme to do that. Does anyone have an idea how to resolved this issue?

Thank you in advance,
Lior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue

[UITheme 'Theme3' Salesforce Classic is returned for Aura component in Lightning Experience Site](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001s8tZQAQ)

Even though it specifies Aura components, the same applies to a Lightning Web Component making the same server side call to get `UserInfo.getUIThemeDisplay`.

In terms of current workarounds, there's none listed on the KI.

However, a field called `UserPreferencesLightningExperiencePreferred` exists on the [User](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_user.htm) object that is tied to the `Switch to Salesforce Classic`/`Switch to Lightning Experience` button on the UI.

> When true, redirects the user to the Lightning Experience interface.
> Label is Switch to Lightning Experience. This field is available in
> API version 35.0 and later.

Your method could be updated to use SOQL to retrieve that field on the user to determine if they're using Lightning or Classic until the bug is fixed with `getUIThemeDisplay`

Comment: Hi, Kris, thank you for replying!
I don't see how using Site.getSiteId() or Site.getSiteType() can help me identifing if the user is using Lightning or Classic UI.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your scenario. `Site.getSiteId()` would be helpful in determining if they're in a community or not (or potentially what type of site if you have many communities) so that doesn't seem to be what you're looking for. I edited the answer to provide an actual workaround to your question.